# ERROR string variable is receiving 0x603270 besides an alphabetic value

Tags: c, cs50

When I type an text, like: "The quick brown fox.", as an input, the debugger shows the value from the variable text is: 0x603270 "The quick brown fox" and the type is an string.

Because of that when it start the for loop, the if statement ISALPHA recive this error: "Process received SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault".

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    // ask the user input
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    // take the text and count how many letters there is (uppercase and lower case)
    for (int i = 0; ;i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text))
        {
            i++;
            return 0;
        }
        else if(isspace(text))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

some one can help me?
why it's showing 0x603270 ? before the correct input ?

Comment: `isalpha` and `isspace` wants a character, not a string, `isalpha(text)` --> `isalpha(text[i])`

Comment: You should not change the difinition of `text`, but you need to 1) check the length of `text` with `strlen`, otherwise you will read outside of the bounds of the array, 2)  do not increment `i` when you find an alpha, use another variable and do not return: https://godbolt.org/z/f8jExW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program crashes at

```c
isalpha(test)
```

Cause you declared

```c
string text
```

the parameter there is a pointer of type `string`. But `isalpha` only accepts an `int` parameter, so just write it as

```c
isalpha(text[i])
```

Same for `isspace`.

Comment: Thanks !!! it works, I also added an ```strlen(text)```  in order to limit the for loop.